# How do you retrieve k prior posts before an id in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do infinite scrolling in reverse where I show the most recent 20 posts initially. As the user scrolls up, I want to retrieve (in Rails) the next 20 recent posts, etc...

The following code almost does it, but it gives the list of posts in reverse order due to "order":

```
room.posts.where('id < ?', id).order('created_at desc').limit(20)
```

I would like the posts in ascending order. I could reverse the array after the retrieval, but that seems like a waste of computation.

On the other hand, if I leave the "order" out (as shown below), this is completely wrong cause then I'd get the 20 earliest posts rather than the 20 most recent.

```
room.posts.where('id < ?', id).limit(20)
```

Comment: Can you describe how you want to show the scrolled pages? Assuming page size is 3 and id 44, then Page 1: `41, 42, 43` and Page 2 will be `38,39,40`. Is this what you need? Usually infinitely scrolled pages are displayed in descending order i.e. page 1: `43, 42, 41`, page 2: `40, 39, 38`.

Comment: I want to show it as what you said in the first case. The way to think about it is as a messaging app, where you see the most recent posts and you scroll up to see the later posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping I understand your problem correctly.  How about:

```
room.posts.where('id < ?', id).order('created_at desc').limit(20).reverse
```

The reverse at the end simply reverses the order of the results in your query.   If this is what you're trying to avoid, I'm not sure how else you'd do it.  This seems like a pretty non-intensive way to get it done.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the reverse, but now that you mention it, I guess it isn't that expensive given that the array size is 20... I'll accept this, but still would be happy if anyone knew a way to get it directly from the database in the right order.